# How to I set a column value from a COUNT subquery that joins with an outer query?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a query (initially written for SQL Server) that have multiple subqueries as columns that computes counts. In SQL server, I'm able to have an equation to have a column set to a count subquery for e.g:

```
Pass = (select count(*) from report.sub_2018 p where p.ABST = a.ABST and p.RESULT = 'P' and p.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' and p.MONTH_YEAR = a.MONTH_YEAR)
```

I'm trying to have the query run in Vertica but it doesn't allow that type of 'equation'. So I tried to do something like

```
(select count(*) from report.sub_2018 p where p.ABST = a.ABST and p.RESULT = 'P' and p.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' and p.MONTH_YEAR = a.MONTH_YEAR) as Pass
```

but since it's correlated with an outer query, i'm getting error `Correlated subquery with aggregate function COUNT is not supported`

This is my query:

```
select UserId = u.USER_ID,
Name = u.LNAME + ', ' + u.FNAME,
a.Month_Year,
(select count(*) from report.sub_2018 p where p.ABST = a.ABST and p.RESULT = 'P' and p.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' and p.MONTH_YEAR = a.MONTH_YEAR) as Pass,
(select count(*) from report.sub_2018 p where p.ABST = a.ABST and p.RESULT = 'F' and p.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' and p.MONTH_YEAR = a.MONTH_YEAR) as Fail,
(select count(*) from report.sub_2018 p where p.ABST = a.ABST and p.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' and p.MONTH_YEAR = a.MONTH_YEAR) as Total
from report.sub_2018 a inner join pd_user_info u on a.ABST = u.USER_ID
where MONTH_YEAR like '2018-%' and u.USER_ID like 'MMN%'
group by u.LNAME, u.FNAME, a.MONTH_YEAR, a.ABST, u.USER_ID
order by u.LNAME, u.FNAME, a.MONTH_YEAR
```

I'm not too sure how to rearrange the query to have it work with the outer query with table `report.sub_2018 a`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this query instead

```
select 
  u.USER_ID as UserId,
  u.LNAME || ', ' || u.FNAME as Name,
  a.Month_Year,
  count(case when a.RESULT = 'P' and a.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' then 1 end) as Pass,
  count(case when a.RESULT = 'F' and a.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' then 1 end) as Fail,
  count(case when                    a.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' then 1 end) as Total
from report.sub_2018 a 
inner join pd_user_info u on a.ABST = u.USER_ID
where MONTH_YEAR like '2018-%' and u.USER_ID like 'MMN%'
group by u.LNAME, u.FNAME, a.MONTH_YEAR, a.ABST, u.USER_ID
order by u.LNAME, u.FNAME, a.MONTH_YEAR
```

This way, you only have to access the `sub_2018` table once. [I have blogged about this technique recently](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/).

Note also, in most other databases than SQL Server, aliasing a column is done using this syntax

```
u.USER_ID as UserId
```

... not this SQL Server specific one:

```
UserId = u.USER_ID
```